# mat-date-picker not valid when typing manualy

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have mat-date-picker with dd/MM/yyyy format,By select in the calandar it's works fine,but when I type manualy a date with day higher then 12,(27/01/2019 for example) its invalid.
html:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="מתאריך" formControlName="dateStart" [(ngModel)]="reportData.dateStart">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker startView="month"></mat-datepicker>
```

**module.ts:**

```
{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' },
```

Something can help?

Comment: most likely because it is taking the american format which is month/day/year. So you cannot go higher than 12 = December.

Comment: check this link for custom date format   https://medium.com/@amandeepkochhar/angular-material-datepicker-set-custom-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-5c0f4340e57

Comment: make input like this <input mdInput placeholder="Title" [ngModel]="mydate  | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'">

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10731

Answer (score 0):

I add a parser:
add new ts file called date-format.ts:

```
import { NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDateFormats } from '@angular/material/core';
export class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
       parse(value: any): Date | null {
        var dateParts = value.split("/");
        if (dateParts.length != 3)
            dateParts = value.split("-");
        if (dateParts.length != 3)
            return null;
        if (dateParts[2] >= 0 && dateParts[2] <= 50)
            dateParts[2] = '20' + dateParts[2];

        return new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0]);
    };
}
```

in app.component:

```
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS} from '@angular/material/core';
import { AppDateAdapter, APP_DATE_FORMATS } from 'src/app/helpers/date-format';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
    providers: [{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: AppDateAdapter},
        {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: APP_DATE_FORMATS}]
})
```